# MIPS load word syntax

Tags: assembly, mips

If I want to load a value from a memory which base address is at $a0 and off set $t2, why can't I do the following:

```
lw  $s2, $a1($t2)
```

so what is the equivalent of the expression above?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do that because there's no MIPS instruction encoding that supports such a thing.  You need to do the addition yourself:

```
add $a2, $a1, $t2
lw  $s2, 0($a2)
```

The `lw` instruction encoding looks like this:

```
1000 11ss ssst tttt iiii iiii iiii iiii
```

Where `sssss` is the source register number, `ttttt` is the destination register number, and `iiiiiiiiiiiiiiii` is the immediate.  There's no room in that encoding (and no alternate instruction encodings) that use two registers to generate the memory address.  The specific machine instruction that would get encoded from the example above is:

```
1000 1100 1101 0010 0000 0000 0000 0000
```

Since the immediate is `0`, `$s2` is register `18` and `$a2` is register `6`.